# Store threads C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to store my threads in a list / vector. If anyone connecting to my local server, the thread [look function incomingConnection(...)] should be stored in a list / vector. The reason is, if I want to shut down my server, i will close all the threads.

myserver.h

```
class MyServer : public QTcpServer{
...
protected:
//create a thread
void incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor);  
public :
std::vector<MyThread*> listOfThreads;
};
```

myserver.cpp

```
void MyServer::incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor){
MyThread* thread = new MyThread(socketDescriptor, this);
connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
thread->start();
listOfThreads.push_back(thread);
}
```

How can i store threads in a list?

Thanks :D

Comment: Did you try the same code as with `vector`? The should be no difference for your task.

Comment: Without having a deeper look, sounds like a thread pool might be more appropriate for what you're trying to achieve. QT provides thread pools ...

Comment: You'll have to store a pointer instead of the object directly since copying a thread doesn't make sense (at least not in this context). That's the only catch though. (Might be worth using a smart pointer by the way.)

Comment: You gave the answer yourself...what is it you want to achieve other than what you are already doing???

Comment: Naked pointer in a `vector`? Ouch.

Comment: To enable people to help you, you need to provide information on what you have already tried and why it didn't work; ideally you should provide a summarized but functional example and compiler errors or faulty runtime output. Not only will it help us help you but it will potentially help you find the problem yourself.

Comment: @TylerJandreau - the problem with smart pointers and thread classes is that the dtor is often non-trivial because of a protracted termination phase that must be performed before thread resources are deallocated. Destroying such multiple threads in a serial fashion can result in a very lengthy shutdown as each of hundreds of client<>server handler threads perform their socket close 4-way handshake, one after the other.

Comment: I have to ask - do you absolutely need to terminate and destroy the threads with user code?  If not, you are making yourself a lot of unnecessary work and pain.

Comment: @MartinJames I didn't know that. Lots of good info in there, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I forgot to include the vector `#include <vector`> in `myserver.h`

Thanks all for feedback